# Can Panache entities be used in non Quarkus managed services?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

using Quarkus 1.9.1

I have a command line application as follows...

```
@CommandLine.Command
public class MyCommandApp {}
```

The application starts a server connection using a 3rd party lib.
At some point when the server accepts a connection it dynamically attaches a listener. For example:

```
if(server.accept())
    server.setListener(new MyServerListener())
```

Inside MyServerListener() can I use a panache entity like this?

```
// This is attached dynamically. There's no Quarkus CDI scope/context to this.
class MyServerLister implements ServerListener {
    @Override
    public void receiveEvent(Event event) {
        MyPanacheEntity.find(...)
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Panache entitites should be usable on Non-CDI beans. If it's not the case please open an issue with a small reproducer.

But Panache can only be used on Quarkus application as it relies on Quarkus build-time enhancements.

Anyway, you can always make your MyServerLister a CDI bean if you want the full power of Quarkus CDI inside it, and inject it inside your `MyCommandApp` and pass it inside your `MyServerLister` constructor for example.

Comment: How do you make it a CDI bean? I can't just put @ApplicationScoped at the class? If you see my example, the listener is created and attached dynamically when the client connects to the server. So it cannot be injected at startup.

Comment: I just understood that you have one listener by client. If it cannot be shared so yes, you cannot make it a CDI bean easily.
Panache can be used on non-CDI bean but need a request scope so it will not work OOTB, see this Zulip thread for more info https://quarkusio.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/187030-users/topic/Using.20panache.20with.20non.20managed.20class.3F